# Como realizar consulta em mais de uma tabela (Wordpress)

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados, wordpress, tabela-banco-de-dados

Como eu faço para realizar uma `QUERY` no banco de dados em 5 tabelas diferentes e retornar os valores que eu quero, exemplo:

Estou realizando um sistema de busca (meu primeiro) e preciso capturar os seguintes valores: Nome do Candidato, Título do Currículo e Categoria da Vaga. Agora vamos as informações:

- O nome do candidato esta na tabela `wp_users`;
- O título do currículo esta na tabela `wp_posts`;
- A categoria da vaga esta na tabela `wp_terms`;
- `wp_users` se relaciona diretamente com `wp_posts`;
- `wp_posts` se relaciona diretamente com `wp_term_relationships`;
- `wp_term_relationships` se relaciona diretamente com `wp_term_taxonomy`;
- `wp_term_taxonomy` se relaciona diretamente com `wp_terms`;
- Mas tem uma condição... Deve ser feita uma consulta na tabela `wp_usermeta` onde `meta_value = '_jm_candidate_field_clocknow_user_btn'` e `meta_key = 'value_1'`;
- A tabela `wp_usermeta` está relacionada diretamente com `wp_users`

`wp_usermeta` -> `wp_users` -> `wp_posts` -> `wp_term_relationships` -> `wp_term_taxonomy` -> `wp_terms`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A consulta que estou fazendo não esta retornando valores:

```
$resultados = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT $wpdb->users.display_name, $wpdb->posts.post_title, $wpdb->terms.name, $wpdb->usermeta.meta_key, $wpdb->usermeta.meta_value 

FROM $wpdb->usermeta 

WHERE $wpdb->usermeta.meta_key = '_jm_candidate_field_clocknow_user_btn' AND $wpdb->usermeta.meta_value = 'value_2' 

INNER JOIN $wpdb->users ON $wpdb->usermeta.user_id = $wpdb->users.ID 

INNER JOIN $wpdb->posts ON $wpdb->posts.post_author = $wpdb->users.ID 

INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships ON $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id = $wpdb->posts.ID 

INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy ON $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id = $wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id 

INNER JOIN $wpdb->terms ON $wpdb->terms.term_id = $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id;" );
```

Seria a lógica que esta errada?

Comment: Só fazer um Inner Join.

Comment: Só utilizando INNER JOIN em uma consulta é possível?

Comment: Possivelmente sim, eu precisaria de mais detalhes (e conhecer melhor a estrutura do banco) pra dizer com certeza.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Nome, Titulo, Categoria FROM wp_users
INNER JOIN wp_posts ON wp_users.id = wp_posts.id
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships ON wp_term_relationships.id = wp_posts.id
INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy ON wp_term_taxonomy.id = wp_term_relationships.id
INNER JOIN wp_terms ON wp_terms.id = wp_term_taxonomy.id;
```

Veja se esse código funciona. Lembrando só que eu nem sei como estão as tabelas, portanto substitua os ids pelas respectivas colunas da tabela.

Comment: Funcionou sim, obrigado! Mas esqueci de um detalhe... tem uma condição que deve ser feita... Na tabela `wp_usermeta` deve ser feita uma verificação onde `meta_value = '_jm_candidate_field_clocknow_user_btn'` e `meta_key = 'value_1'`. A tabela wp_usermeta é relacionada diretamente com wp_users. Aqui uma imagem da relação das tabelas (https://codex.wordpress.org/images/2/25/WP4.4.2-ERD.png)

Answer (score -3):

como seria para uma paginação nesta lista de resultado eu fiz um foreach que repete os registros, mas se tiver digamos 100 resultados, como dividir em 10 paginas com links de navegação de paginação?